# EXCEPT it exits in 2 other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, except, sql-except

I need to get all values from table product , EXCEPT they exits in 2 other table products. Is this query acceptable using 2 EXCEPTS ? Should this be done differently .

```
CREATE table missing_values
AS
select post
from product
EXCEPT
select post
from product_table_a
EXCEPT
select post
from product_table_b
;
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If a value exists in `product` and only ONE of the other two tables, should it be excluded by your query ?  Or should it only be excluded if it exists in BOTH of the other two tables?  Also ***have you actually tried it yourself***?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Please don't make edits that add no material benefit.

Comment: @ MatBailie - If there is a value in product table not found in product_table_a or product_table_b it should be added to the missing_values table being created , this is it.

Comment: x-posted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/114370/7788

Comment: @Craig Ringer . Right first posted at dba , there was no audience . Than posted here . Thanks for noticing

Comment: @JorgeVidinha No probs. The cross links just help people find it and reduce time wasted by asking duplicate followup questions. It's nice if you include cross links in the question if you're going to post multiple places. BTW, remember timezones and people's work. 8 hours isn't "no audience", it's just "not answered instantly"

Comment: @CraigRinger good to know , thanks. Btw any advice on the question ?

Comment: @JorgeVidinha Existing answers are fine.

Comment: Related answer with basic techniques: [Select rows which are not present in other table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` - `B` - `C` is the same as `A` - (`B` + `c`):

```
SELECT post
FROM product
EXCEPT
(
  SELECT post
  FROM product_table_a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT post
  FROM product_table_b
) AS sum;
```

Comment: Just wondering. Any reason to use `union all` over just `union` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `UNION ALL` is faster and doesn't require sorting

Answer (score 2):

As MatBailie say, you should try your query and see if that give you the result you want.

But in case that doesnt work you can solve it with a double `not exists`

This mean `p1` isn't found neither in `p2` or `p3`.

```
SELECT post
FROM product p1
WHERE not exists (SELECT p2.post                       
                  FROM product_table_a p2
                  WHERE p1.post = p2.post)
AND   not exists (SELECT p3.post                       
                  FROM product_table_b p3
                  WHERE p1.post = p3.post)
```

Also this is a probably a more eficient way

```
SELECT post
FROM product p1
left join product_table_a p2
   on p1.post = p2.post
left join product_table_b p3
   on p1.post = p3.post
WHERE p2.post is null
and   p3.post is null
```

Comment: For what it is worth [using `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` is no more or less efficient in Postgresql](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/) than using `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @GarethD I didn't knew that.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yep. The query planner typically produces the same plan for either form.